# Trouble with float object

Tags: python, cursor, arcpy

I am trying to append the list of data to an attribute table but I keep getting the same error

```
for field in fields:
arcpy.AddField_management(equal_shape, field[0], field[1])
print "step 3"

total_area = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(equal_shape, ("OID@", "SHAPE@AREA")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print("Feature {0} has an area of {1}".format(row[0], row[1]))
print "step 4"

sum_area = sum(total_area)
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(equal_shape, ["TOT_AREA"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = total_area
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
 sum_area = sum(total_area)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `total_area` is not the list that is expected - compare with `sum(1.234)`. Why not? (Is the file *saved*?) Alternatively, the reported error is wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to programming. So why isn't `total_area` the expected list, and should I save it first? Thanks

Comment: You instantiated `total_area` as an empty list and then didn't add anything to it in.